# How to convert the 6020494385.89982 string value to double

Tags: java, string, double

How to convert the `"6020494385.89982"` string value to a double?

```
String ss = "6020494385.89982";
double dd = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(ss));
System.out.println(dd);
```

I am getting the output as
`6.02049438589982E9` but I want `6020494385.89982` as double value.

Comment: `6.02049438589982E9` is only a String representation of the double, just check that `dd == 6020494385.89982;`

Comment: Thanks Berger. Yes dd == 6020494385.89982 works fine. But how I will get the actual value 6020494385.89982 from 6.02049438589982E9.

Answer (score 5):

Use of a `DecimalFormat`object should do the trick

```
String ss = "6020494385.89982";
double dd = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(ss));
System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("#0.00000").format(dd));
```

Or you can use `System.out#printf()`

```
System.out.printf("%.5f", dd);
```

Because `System.out.println` has a particular way of working with double precisions that will not work in this particular case for example.

Answer (score 2):

The number is correct. `6.02049438589982E9` is just the scientific notation, which is the default when you print a `double`. If you want the non-scientific notation, you could just use `printf` instead of `println`:

```
System.out.printf("%f\n", dd);
```

Comment: What is the difference between `System.out.printf` and `System.out.format`?

Comment: @WilliamRosenbloom Here is a part of the JavaDoc of `System.out.printf` : `An invocation of this method of the form out.printf(format, args) behaves in exactly the same way as the invocation  out.format(format, args) `

Answer (score 1):

`6.02049438589982E9` is the same as `6020494385.89982`

`6.02049438589982E9` = `6.02049438589982 X 10^9`

the value stored in the double is 6020494385.89982 However, when you print it out, it represents in this format: `6.02049438589982E9`

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to convert into double if in the end you want the representation in the same format as the current value of ss variable.

However if you need to convert for some other purpose and then need to show in that format later/else where you can use **DecimalFormat** as others have suggested.